# Strange result from flat file import

Tags: sql-server, format, ssms, varchar, nvarchar

I am trying to import a .csv UTF-8 BOM file, but keep getting a really strange result. One column holds the value of the year, for now only 2016. I have tried importing it as varchar, nvarchar and char, but the result is always that all values are stored like '20:16' and not '2016'.

Furthermore, I have a VariableName column which is simple enough; 'R1', 'R2'... and so on. As with the year column, I have tried to store it as various formats, but the leading 'R' is always stripped…

Cannot figure it out, would be grateful for hints!

Comment: How are you importing the file, with `BULK INSERT`? If you are, if change the format to a supported encode (assuming you aren't using SQL Server 2019 preview) does the problem persist?

Comment: Hi, thank you, sorry for not responding sooner. I've sort of abandoned this method in favour of Reading data straight from R to SQL. However, I did not use BULK INSERT.